# OOP, assignment operator does not work

Tags: c++

This is from my code:

```
struct R3
{
       float x;
       float y;
       float z;

       R3(float, float, float);
       R3();
};

R3::R3(float a, float b, float c)
{
        x = a;
        y = b;
        z = c;
}

R3::R3()
{
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        z = 0;
}

struct Bodies
{
       int Mass;
       float Dist[100];
       R3 Place(float, float, float);
       R3 Speed(float, float, float);
       R3 Acc(float, float, float);

       Bodies(int, R3, R3, R3);
};

Bodies::Bodies(int M, R3 XYZ, R3 V, R3 A)
{
       Mass = M;
       Place = XYZ;
       Speed.x = V.x;
       Speed.y = V.y;
       Speed.z = V.z;
       Acc.x = A.x;
       Acc.y = A.y;
       Acc.z = A.z;
}
```

My problem is, that for Place = XYZ;, it's showing the error "invalid use of member (did you forget the '&'?)"
and for Speed.x = V.x; "insufficient contextual information to determine type".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Place, Speed and Acc members are declared as functions. 
Use:

```
struct Bodies
{
       int Mass;
       float Dist[100];
       R3 Place;
       R3 Speed;
       R3 Acc;
```

instead.

And use initialization in the constructor:

```
Bodies::Bodies(int M, R3 XYZ, R3 V, R3 A): Mass(M), Place(XYZ), Speed( V ), Acc( A ){}
```

instead of assignment.

Comment: @Tom83B: If this is the answer that helped you solve the problem, you might want to accept it. See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 1):

`Place` is a member function taking three `floats`, and you are trying to assign to it in the constructor.  You can't do that.  Perhaps you meant for `Place` to be a data member of type `R3`:

```
struct Bodies
{
    ...
    R3 Place;
    R3 Speed;
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

These are functions declarations :

```
R3 Place(float, float, float);
R3 Speed(float, float, float);
R3 Acc(float, float, float);
```

not object creations.